# Delay repeat animation in reverse mode

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity, android-animation

I'm trying to add some delay to to the repeat animation, but startDelay isn't work. It looks like it wonly works when the animation is played for the first time.

```
val path = Path().apply {
    moveTo(imageView.x, imageView.y)
    lineTo(x.toFloat(), y.toFloat())
}
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.X, View.Y, path).apply {
    duration = Random.nextLong(500, 1000)
    startDelay = 1000
    doOnEnd {
    startDelay = 3000
    } 
start()
}
```

I also tried to use `Timer` and `Handler().postDelayed` but it doesn't even repeat:

```
val path = Path().apply {
    moveTo(imageView.x, imageView.y)
    lineTo(x.toFloat(), y.toFloat())
}
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.X, View.Y, path).apply {
    duration = Random.nextLong(500, 1000)
    startDelay = 1000
    doOnStart {
        Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                repeatCount = 1
                repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
             }
        }, 3000)
    }
 start()
}
```

How can I achieve the repeat in reverse mode delayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code for simulating the delay for the animation.

The pause/delay/resume will do the trick for you.

```
val path = Path().apply {
    moveTo(imageView.x, imageView.y)
    lineTo(x.toFloat(), y.toFloat())
}

val delayBetweenRepeats = 2_000L

ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.X, View.Y, path).apply {
    duration = Random.nextLong(500, 1000)
    startDelay = 1000
    repeatCount = 5
    repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
    doOnRepeat {
        pause()
        Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                runOnUiThread { resume() }
            }
        }, delayBetweenRepeats)
    }
    start()
}
```